# Setting labels as background labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to set labels as background labels in QGIS ?
See [this page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/setting-labels-as-background-labels.htm) to see what i mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [Label Z index](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#rendering-tab)

To reproduce the background labels effect you need to give your label a lower Z index than of other label (you may also need to tweak other setting to allow overlap).

[image]